# Purpose of some "mounting points" on a suspension fork? (left rear side, 2 eyelets)

Tags: brakes, suspension

I recently bought a bike equipped with a Fox 34 AWL suspension fork (pictured below).

[image: Fox 24 AWL]

As it is shown on the picture, the left leg has 5 mounting points: the 3 lower ones are clearly identified: caliper and fender. The right leg has only one mounting point, for the fender.

What could be the purpose of the 2 upper ones on the left leg? Fox's page speaks about a *[special mount for a soon to be available, next level safety feature](https://www.ridefox.com/family.php?m=bike&family=awl)*, which doesn't really help. They are on the 'inside side', so can't be used as mounting points for bags, as it is commonly the case in gravel forks (and if it were the case, they should have been on both sides anyway).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From [Bike Rumor](https://bikerumor.com/fox-awl-fork-is-a-stiffer-34mm-stanchion-fork-with-all-the-mounts-for-emtbs-and-e-suvs/) website I found this.

"As such, the AWL gets an integrated fender (see second image for reference), with mounts for a light and a rack. There are also mounts for “a soon to be available next level safety feature”. Though we can’t say for sure, this may well be an anti-lock braking system, such as the ABS G2 from BluBrake, to prevent undesirable front wheel skids."

[This article](https://www.bikeperfect.com/news/blubrakes-smaller-g2-abs-system-re-ignites-the-off-road-braking-debate) has images of the Bluebrake G2 module mounted on the left fork lower.

Comment: Thanks, seems indeed like the most plausible answer. Just interesting that the bikes that now ship with ABS have [different placements](https://favbike.de/news/canyon-pathliteon-9-ltd-suv-smarter-e-allrounder-mit-bosch-abs/attachment/canyon-pathlite-on-9-ltd-suv-e-trekkingbike-bosch-abs-7/). But given the article you linked to is now 2 years old, it's probably a "failed attempt".

Answer (score 2):

On many European bicycles, the front light and bottle dynamo are mounted near the location of these eyelets, though usually by clamping around the left pipe of the fork, not by any eyelets.  The eyelets may thus be for AWL's suggested light accessory.

The front light itself may sit down on the left with the dynamo, or on further up above the wheel, either way it points in the direction of the front wheel.

These traditional bottle dynamos have a button released spring that causes the dynamo to press against the left side of the wheel to get 6V AC power for the lights as the bicycle moves.  In daytime, the dynamo is tilted away to not slow down the bicycle.  An electrical wire through the bicycle frame and rear fender connects the dynamo to the rear light.

Comment: That's indeed a very good point to keep for further reference, however this suspension range (AWL) is meant specifically for e-bikes, that do not need dynamos. From what I've seen on my other bike, support for cables are quite different, and meant to protect the cable: [example from the Rockshox Paragon](https://images.bike24.net/i/mb/84/b1/6b/206318-03-d-390512.jpg)

Comment: Even on an e-bike, the front light may be mounted in the same position as on a fully human powered bicycle.  Also, I doubt that fork isn't also usable on such bicycles.

Comment: The front light is usually mounted so that it points forward, and those mounting points are behind the fork.

Comment: This fork can work of course work on a non-electric bike, but that wouldn't make it the most sensible choice (500g heavier and more expensive because it's rated for a total mass 170kg instead of 120kg) - and no cable routing from the hub.

Answer (score 1):

(guessing)   Perhaps a clamping point for the hose/cable to the front disk brake caliper?

If left to flap, this hose either risks touching the wheel or catching a passing branch.   The common fix of a cable tie tends to abrade the paint at that point.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I showed the picture of the fork alone for clarity, but this was a clamping point for the hose, it would have been used on the full bike, which is not the case. The hose is attached on the front of the part that holds the two legs of the lowers (this clamp is visible on the photo). These two mounts are really left unused on the assembled bike.

Comment: @Renaud That part is usually referred to as the fork's arch. And yes, the hose mount is indeed on the NDS of the arch in that photo.